# echo in codeigniter controller is not working

Tags: jquery, codeigniter-2

echo in codeigniter controller is not working.. Is there any setting in config to enable echo in codeigniter. All other files are working except those which are having echo in controllers.

```
 <?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }
}
```

Basically iam testing jquery and condeigniter sample script given in http://www.ryantetek.com/2009/12/how-to-create-a-simple-ajax-post-in-codeigniter-using-jquery. but i found script is not working because echo statement in controller.
please help me.

error: "This webpage is not available"..

Answer (score 3):

I have face the same problem but only in mac browsers and i fixed that with this one
In your `./application/config/config.php` file check `$config['compressed_output']` if it set to true then make it false as some browsers does not support compressed output.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct. You are likely accessing the wrong path. Do not load the controller directly, because CodeIgniter does freaky stuff with URLs--instead, load a URL similar to the following:

http://yoursite.com/code_igniter_path/index.php/blog/index

Good luck!

Comment: You don't need the `/index`.  `index` is the default function, you can just do `http://yoursite.com/code_igniter_path/index.php/blog`.

Comment: That is very true. I provided it to clarify so that he'd better understand how the CodeIgniter architecture works in the event he decides to expand the example in his experimentation.

To user1130639: you are welcome to access the URL with or without the /index, but you *will* need the /whatever at the end if you extend this example.

Comment: iam using xampp in my local desktop..path is http://localhost/ci/index.php/blog/ ( i installed CI in CI folder of htdocs. all others controllers are working fine .. only controllers with echo statement are not working)

Comment: Hmm, odd. Can you confirm that the controller is named `blog.php`, and is located in the `/controllers/` folder?

Comment: yes it is blog.php and also it is in controllers folder and all other files in controllers folder are working

Comment: What happens when you put `$this->load->view('VIEW_NAME');` right after the echo statement? Does the view load that way?

Comment: its not working. but if i remove echo.. its working fine. this is the line i added after echo statement.. `<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

 public function index()
 {
  $data['message']='Hello World!';
  //echo $data['message'];
  $this->load->view('welcome_message');
 }
}`

Comment: welcome_message.php is default view that comes with ci. i used the same

Comment: It should be working--I'm not sure why it's not. I recommend you try posting in the CodeIgniter support forums--perhaps somewhere there will be better able to assist you. I have never seen this problem before, and do not understand why it would be occurring, unless your server has some odd configuration.