# codeginiter json output error

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter

Iam trying to return json data from codeigniter view. but my code is not working.i have tried all options given in this site. but i could not able to return json data from view
this is controller code.

```
<?php
class Json extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('get_json');
        $data['message']=$this->get_json->get_fruits();

         if ($data!== false)
         {
                    $this->load->view('json',json_encode($data['message']));
        }
    }
}
```

my model

```
<?php

    class get_json extends CI_Model
    {
        function __construct()
        {
           parent::__construct();
        }


        function get_fruits()
        {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM fruit where name='Apple'";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            // Fetch the result array from the result object and return it
            return $query->result();

        }

    }
```

View code:

```
<?php
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
echo $message;
```

Please help me wwhere my code went wrong.

This is what iam getting in my logs:

```
ERROR - 2012-05-11 15:28:40 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined variable: message C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\system\core\Loader.php(829) : eval()'d code 3
DEBUG - 2012-05-11 15:28:40 --> File loaded: application/views/json.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your controller `index` method to this:

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('get_json');
        $data['message']= json_encode($this->get_json->get_fruits());

         if ($data!== false)
         {
                    $this->load->view('json',$data);
        }
}
```

And you should be good to go: you need to pass the array to `$this->load->view`, not the encoded value.

EDIT: as a side note, for this sort of thing you don't even NEED a view. You can return the result directly from the controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('get_json');
        $message = $this->get_json->get_fruits();

         if ($message !== false)
         {
                    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
                    echo json_encode($message);
        }
}
```

Cleaner, puts everything in one place, and slightly more efficient.

Comment: echo in my controller is not working. iam still finding fix ..[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520423/echo-in-codeignter-controller-is-not-working[/link]